# How can I increase the width of a gvim window?

Tags: gvim

I know that with gvim, I can use the following command to set the width of a window:

```
set columns=80
```

How can I do the same, but instead of setting the width, increasing it by a certain value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:set columns+=10
```

See [`:help :set+=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:set+=).